# Unique number from digits 0123456789 with simple property

Tags: mathematics, puzzle-creation

It would be fun to have a puzzle "Find the only 10-digit number having each digit once AND property xyz", but offhand I don't know any "simple" xyz. "Is a square" gives far too many results, other powers don't work (up to 10). "Is prime" of course is an epic fail.
Do you know any puzzle of this type? "Smallest/Largest such" is cheating :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is an example of what you are looking for

> Find the only 10-digit number having each digit once such that the number formed by the first $n$ digits is divisible by $n$, for each $n$ from $1$ to $10$.

I'll leave it to the reader to find it for themselves.

Comment: That is a very nice property! 

Comment: This is the example I immediately thought of, too.

Comment: Now that you say, I immediately remember it :-)

Comment: Meta-Problem: Does this only work in base 10? I hacked together a Python code, no or more than 1 solution in all bases<10 (except unary or binary) or 11. 12 is already too slow for me.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann Some conditions on possible solutions in other bases b. b must be even for any solutions to exist. Odd digits must go in odd places and even digits in even places. The b/2th place is always b/2.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I checked 12 and 14. 12 has no solutions and 14 has a unique solution. Wasn't able to check 16.